# Mount volume with docker-compose for Jupyter and RStudio instance

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, docker-volume

I am learning Docker and managed to create a *RStudio instance* and a *Jupyter Notebook* instance using *docker-compose* building an image.
While I can log in and create scripts from the instances, I noticed these scripts are not saved "persistently", and I cannot find them in my main folders `/home/rstudio_scripts` and `home/jupyter_scripts`.

I have learned that in order for the scripts/data created in these instances to be "persistent" even after docker containers are down, you need to mount volumes.

So I have tried to mount volumes and create a specific folder for RStudio & Jupyter in the docker-compose.yml below:

[image]

But there is clearly something wrong as neither the folders nor the data appear.

My *docker-compose.yml* and the *Dockerfile* for RStudio are both in a folder called *Docker*, that is within this folder that I am building the image docker `build -t general_docker .`

I would also like that any data created either in the Rstudio or Jupyter instance can be read/write by both instances, but I don't know if I should use something like `chmod 777 ...` after, when the containers are running.

Any help much appreciated !

**EDIT 1**: Let me attach the updated docker-compose.yml. The following allow me to have a new folder I created in the home directory called *R_and_Jupyter_scripts* containing all my scripts, to be accessible in my Rstudio instance as well as my Jupyter notebook. But I would like that any new script created from the Jupyter or RStudio instance does not disappear after doing 'docker-compose down'. What part of the *docker-compose.yml* should I change?

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rstudio:
    environment:
      - USER=username
      - PASSWORD=password
    image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    build:
     context: ./
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - $HOME/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/rstudio/r_scripts
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
     - 8787:8787

  jupyter:
    image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - $HOME/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/jovyan/work
    container_name: jupyter
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have edited the code above to write in volumes only absolute paths (see below) but still does not do what I need.

I have created a text file `output.txt` from RStudio and when I do `sudo find / -name "output.txt"` I expect this file to be in `/home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts`
but it ends up being in two different places that look like folders that are still in the container itself:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/66513c53c04786298cac012ea032be58d434131ce04e73f75bf63ca1d0e358d6/diff/home/maxence/r_scripts/output.txt
```

and

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/66513c53c04786298cac012ea032be58d434131ce04e73f75bf63ca1d0e358d6/merged/home/maxence/r_scripts/output.txt
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rstudio:
    environment:
      - USER=username
      - PASSWORD=password
    image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    build:
     context: ./
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/rstudio/r_scripts
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
     - 8787:8787

  jupyter:
    image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/jovyan/work
    container_name: jupyter
```

Comment: Do not post images of code. Paste the code itself, redacting any passwords, etc. that are redacted in the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `volume` definition creates folders *inside* the container. If you want to mount a folder on your Docker host, you must give the full path to that host folder; just the relative local folder name is not sufficient.

The config you posted is using a "named volume", instead of mounting a host volume. It acts close enough to a disk image; Docker will have a reference to a `{PROJECT}_Docker` volume when you run `docker volume ls`. This saves the contents of the folder elsewhere, not normally accessible except via mounting in other Docker containers.

If you want to host volume mount, remove the `volumes:` section at the end of the Compose file, and instead have in each service definition something like

```
volumes:
  - /home/ML_Enthousiast/my_project/Docker:/home/rstudio_scripts
```

Comment: Thanks @wmorrell I removed "named volume" and updated my script above. Although I should have mentionned more clearly in my initial post, my need is that any new data or script created, remains "persistent" even when I do docker-compose down.

Comment: Data written to a directory mounted via `volumes` will persist to that volume. I suggest you review the Docker documentation on volumes, it should help in understanding what's happening. Your updated config I do not think will work, values under the `volumes` key must be a colon-delimited string with the first part being either a named volume or an absolute path on the host, the second part being the path *inside the container* where the volume is available, and optional third part with mount options (e.g. readonly). I do not think `$HOME` is valid, use the real path.

Comment: Thx @wmorrell, I updated the script with absolute paths and more info. I have been through the docker volumes tutorials but can't find one that is explicit to me.

Comment: From your update, it sounds like the containers were never re-created, and you are still using containers launched from the original configuration, with a named volume. This has reached a point where it's no longer helpful to go back-and-forth in comments. Try finding someone you can sit with in person to troubleshoot, or sign up for a class on Docker.